# Writing/Reading Files and Exceptions

Tags: java, file-io

When I run my code, the output is this:

```
4 went down to the market
0   where she bought herself
1 
0 kitten
0  she thought the 
6 was
0     precious,
2 she
0  named the kitten
String index out of range: -1
```

But the **desired output** is suppose to be this:

```
0 Lisa went down to the market
3 where she bought herself
0 a 
1 kitten
2 she thought the 
0 kitten was
5 precious,
0 so she
2 named the kitten
0 Princess
```

I was given a text file,http://pastebin.com/h51eh8EX, that contained lines of text. I have to write a class that reads the text,counts number of spaces at the beginning of each line, and write the lines to remove the blanks at the beginning of each line and replace them with a count of the number of blanks present.

Can you explain to me whats my problem?

Here is the code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Squeeze {
    String fname;//name of the file that contains text to be squeezed

    /**
     * Constructor to initialize fname
     * @param name - name of the file to be squeezed
     */
    public Squeeze(String name)
    {
            //TODO Your code goes here
            fname = name;
    }
    /**
     * Method to remove and count any extra
     * leading spaces
     *
     */
    public void squeezeText()
    {
            //TODO Your code goes here
            try
    {
        File file = new File("squeeze.txt");
       Scanner in = new Scanner(file);
        while (in.hasNext())
        {

            String line = in.nextLine();  
            int count = line.substring(0, line.indexOf(" ")).length();
            line = count + line.substring(line.indexOf(" "));
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        in.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println( "Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }

    }
}
```

Comment: you need to attempt it. We aren't a homework service. If you want to pay me though I'll do it for you!

Comment: @75inchpianist - it sounds like it was attempted - see the second pastebin link.

Answer (score 0):

Using indexOf() is inaccurate for this because it only gives you the first occurance of the space character.

Java String API: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Answer (score 0):

Your counting method is off, it's probably easiest to just loop over the characters. Here is one way you can do that -

```
while (in.hasNext()) {
  String line = in.nextLine();
  int count = 0;
  for (char c : line.toCharArray()) {
    if (c == ' ') {
      count++;
    }
  }
  line = count + " " + line;
  System.out.println(line);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use regex

```
 while (in.hasNext())
 {
    String line = in.nextLine();    
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^\\s+\\w");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
    if (m.find()) {
            System.out.println(m.group().length() - 1 + " " + line);
    } else {
            System.out.println("0" + " " + line);
    }
}
```